# How can I get the state of a program?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, thread-state

I'm observing an program and want to kill it, if it is for some time in the state "wait:executive".

Here is a screenshot of the Process Explorer:

[image: State: wait:executive]

**How can I get that state by code?** Or could maybe tell me somebody what that state exactly mean? This will may help me to find the right query to solve my problem.

Comment: Information should be somewhere in PCB of a process. Is this windows 8?

Comment: No that is in Windows 7.

Comment: It's perfectly normal for the main thread of an application to be waiting

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That is in my case a console application which should do its work and exit. But when I start it from my vb script the application hangs in some (reproducible) cases. But it works with the same command line in cmd fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not state of program but it's state of thread.One process can have many threads.

You can call [WaitForSingleObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to determine some states.

Also you can instantiate WMI using COM and selecting [Win32_Thread class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394494.aspx).

[Here is some example.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa390423%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

More info here : [How to determine that a win32 thread is either in Wait or Join or Sleep state in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8185437/how-to-determine-that-a-win32-thread-is-either-in-wait-or-join-or-sleep-state-in)

Comment: Thank you for that hints. I'll need some time to understand and implement that.

Answer (score 2):

It means the thread is waiting for the scheduler/a component of the executive

It can be fetched with WMI [`Win32_Thread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394494.aspx) (or .net `System.Diagnostics.ProcessThread WaitReason`)